# Playing video yeild black screen with audio(Vlc.DotNet and libvlcsharp)

Tags: c#, winforms, vlc, libvlcsharp, vlc.dotnet

I have a simple `WinForms` solution with 2 video players one is [Vlc.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet) and the second is [libvlcsharp](https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp)

and besides that, I have a simple button that plays both videos.

for `libvlcsharp` i followed [this](https://codesailer.com/tutorials/simple_video_player/) example

and for `Vlc.DotNet` i used [this](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/tree/develop/src/Samples/Samples.WinForms.Minimal) example

further more im attaching both logFiles
[Loglibvlcsharp.txt](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/716946517772206131/907587439718182962/LogLib.txt) and [LogVlcDotNet](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/716946517772206131/907567287387701308/Logs.log)

this is my code

```
public partial class QueueDisplayVideoView : Form
{
    private string[] paths, files;
    private int videoIndex = 0;

    public LibVLC _libVLC;
    public MediaPlayer _mp;
    public LibVLCSharp.Shared.Media media;

    public QueueDisplayVideoView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Core.Initialize();
        _libVLC = new LibVLC(enableDebugLogs:true);
        _libVLC.SetLogFile(@"C:\Temp\LogLib.txt");
        _mp = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);
        videoView.MediaPlayer = _mp;

    }


    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {           
        _presenter.OnViewReady();
        base.OnLoad(e);

        LoadVideoFiles();
        SetPlayerAspectRatio();
        //StartAutoPlay();
    }

    private void StartAutoPlay()
    {
        vlcControl.Play(new Uri(paths[videoIndex]));
        _mp.Play(new LibVLCSharp.Shared.Media(_libVLC, new Uri(paths[videoIndex])));
    }

    private void LoadVideoFiles()
    {     
        var path = some path
        paths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        files = new string[paths.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
        {
            files[i] = Path.GetFileName(paths[i]);
        }
    
    }

    private void SetPlayerAspectRatio()
    {
        var videoWidth = vlcControl.Width.ToString();
        var videoHieght = vlcControl.Height.ToString();
        vlcControl.Video.AspectRatio = videoWidth + ":" + videoHieght;
    }

    private void vlcControl_VlcLibDirectoryNeeded(object sender, Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcLibDirectoryNeededEventArgs e)
    {
        // var currentAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        var currentDirectory = @"Q:\bin";  //new FileInfo(currentAssembly.Location).DirectoryName;
        // Default installation path of VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64");
        e.VlcLibDirectory =  new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
    }


    private void vlcControl_EndReached(object sender, Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayerEndReachedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetNextVideoIndex();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => vlcControl.Play(new Uri(paths[videoIndex])));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartAutoPlay();
    }

    private void GetNextVideoIndex()
    {
        if (videoIndex < files.Length - 1)
        {
            videoIndex = videoIndex + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            videoIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a codec issue. Does the same video play with VLC stand alone?

Comment: yes and i also installed latest VLC just to be safe

Comment: this is not a reproducible sample code

Comment: @mfkl care to explain why?

Comment: There is no repo to clone and run, there is no sample video

Comment: @mfkl you can just choose any sample video from the internet, and you can just copy and paste the code

Comment: Does your Q:\ bin have all the required files and folders? (especially the plugin folder?) Why didn't you install libvlc through the nuget package? It doesn't seem like you've followed the tutorials properly, so, as mfkl suggested, a repro project might help

Comment: @cube45 yes, any i used windows media player to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/axwindowsmediaplayer-object--vb-and-c)?

it should be **native** to winforms,
all you have to do choose the right **.dll at toolbox-> choose items-> com compoents-> windows media player.**

Comment: this is an alternative, not a solution